# Convert function from cartesian coordinates to cylindrical and spherical

Tags: coordinate-systems, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

**Introduction**

I have a point charge of magnitude $-6Q_0$. This point charge is placed in the origin of an orthogonal coordinate system. The electric field at a arbitrary point $P=(x,y,z)$ caused by this point charge can be expressed by the function $$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=\mathbf{a_x}\Bigg(\frac{k_c \cdot-6Q_0 \cdot x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \Bigg) + \mathbf{a_y}\Bigg(\frac{k_c \cdot-6Q_0 \cdot y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \Bigg) + \mathbf{a_z}\Bigg(\frac{k_c \cdot-6Q_0 \cdot z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \Bigg)$$

Where $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)$ is the electric field at a point $P=(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{a_x,a_y,a_z}$ are unit vectors pointing towards the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis respectively. $k_c$ is just a constant.

**Note:** The expression for the above electric field is derived through Coulomb's law:
$$\mathbf{E}=k_c\cdot\frac{Q}{|r|^2}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|r|} $$

**Problem**

How can I express the electric field at a given point $P$ in terms of cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

That is, how do I convert my expression from cartesian coordinates to cylindrical and spherical so that the expression for the electric field looks like this for the cylindrical:

$$\mathbf{E}(r,\phi,z) $$

And like this for the spherical coordinatsystem:

$$\mathbf{E}(R,\theta,\phi) $$

Is there some method to convert an entire expression into a different coordinate system? I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Better to derive Coulomb's Law directly in terms of cyl/ sph coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C= -6 Q_0 k_c$.   Using standard resolution of vectors

*Cylindrical*

$$ E(r,\phi,z) =\dfrac{ C(r \cos \phi, r \sin\phi,z)}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac32}} $$

*Spherical*

$$ {E(R,\phi,\theta)=\dfrac{ C(\cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi  \sin \theta,\sin\phi)} {R^2} } $$

Or in the form you have written in your comment:

$$\mathbf{E}(r,\phi,z)=\mathbf{a_r}(\frac{C \cdot r\cos(\phi)}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})+\mathbf{a_{\phi}}(\frac{C \cdot r\sin(\phi)}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})+\mathbf{a_z}(\frac{C \cdot z}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not sure how you arrive at these expressions. Also, I don't quite understand the notation, what does the comma between the factors mean, like at $r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta$? @Narasimham

Comment: We can also denote vector components in cartesian coordinates $ (a_x,a_y,a_z) $ separately instead of $( a_x i+ a_y j+ a_z k) $

Comment: Ahh okay, so cylindrincal expression would be written like this using my original notation: $\mathbf{E}(r,\phi,z)=\mathbf{a_r}(\frac{C \cdot r\cos(\phi)}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})+\mathbf{a_{\phi}}(\frac{C \cdot r\sin(\phi)}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})+\mathbf{a_z}(\frac{C \cdot z}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})$? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: it is okay, similarly the spherical part.